# Django datetimes queryset in 1.5

Tags: python, django, postgresql, datetime, timezone

How to get the new Django 1.6 datetimes queryset in Django 1.5 assuming I've postgres database?

Ref datetimes here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/querysets/#datetimes

I want a timezone aware aggregation of datetimes and not in UTC. But this is mentioned as a limitation in Django 1.5
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/models/querysets/#dates

Comment: Upgrade to Django 1.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have no way other than upgrading to `Django 1.6`.